# Prism ContainerLocator

Tags: prism

In 2020 Haukinger wrote on these forms:

> So, with Prism 8, you write Prism.Ioc.ContainerLocator.Container

I am using Prism 8.1.97 and I can find no such ContainerLocator using the Visual Studio Object Browser, in any of the Prism namespaces. Nor will Intellisense recognize it (I have

```
using Prism.Ioc
```

at the top of the program.) What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reference `Prism.Core`

[See the source at github.](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/7f0b1680bbe754da790274f80851265f808d9bbf/src/Prism.Core/Ioc/ContainerLocator.cs)

Comment: Thanks, that's the ticket. I had a reference to Prism.Wpf which in turn had a reference to Prism.Core. However, that did not work. I had to remove Prism.Wpf and make a top level reference for Prism.Core. Frankly, even though it is a wpf project not sure why I added or need Prism.Wpf instead of just Prism.

Comment: It depends on which features you want to use... I've worked a project once that used just the event aggregator and nothing else.

Comment: Prism.Core worked well for using ContainerLocator but now I find the legacy code depended on ModulesConfigurationSection to load modules from modules.config which is only available in Prism.wpf! Between a rock and a hard place, assuming you have to use or the other in a single solution.

Comment: One project can reference more than one nuget package, e.g. `Prism.Core` and `Prism.Wpf`, just make sure that you chose versions that are compatible.

Comment: With your encouragement I added Prism.Wpf back in. My hesitation was both Prism.Core and Prism.Wpf appear to both have methods and/or properties for Containers and/or Modules. So were they dueling banjos competing for attention or more like a piano and drums each performing separate roles? Appears to be the latter. I have the legacy code upgraded and working now - thanks once again.